# cv use of undeclared identifier in Xcode C++

Tags: opencv, installation

I imported the frameworks to my project in Xcode, and included the header files, but still it isn't recognizing.

[image: screenshot of error in xcode]

Comment: Please cut and paste your code, rather than including a screenshot. People who want to search or reproduce your problem will have more success that way.

Comment: @user3486184 you should vote/flag to close this kind of questions until an edit is made with the relevant copy-paste.

Comment: why not invest in a image recognition algorithm ?